# Math Algorithm Challenge

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typescript, math, logarithm

Why does this solution work?
most people are doing loops to solve this and i did recursion,
but this is easy as hell, for the computer, i am so confused why does this work?

Description:
A child is playing with a ball on the nth floor of a tall building. The height of this floor, h, is known.

He drops the ball out of the window. The ball bounces (for example), to two-thirds of its height (a bounce of 0.66).

His mother looks out of a window 1.5 meters from the ground.

How many times will the mother see the ball pass in front of her window (including when it's falling and bouncing?

Three conditions must be met for a valid experiment:
Float parameter "h" in meters must be greater than 0
Float parameter "bounce" must be greater than 0 and less than 1
Float parameter "window" must be less than h.
If all three conditions above are fulfilled, return a positive integer, otherwise return -1.

Note:
The ball can only be seen if the height of the rebounding ball is stricty greater than the window parameter.

```
export class G964 {
    public static bouncingBall(h: number, bounce: number, window: number): any {
        if (h <= 0 || bounce >= 1 || bounce <= 0 || window >= h) {
          return -1
        }

        return 1 + 2 * (Math.ceil(Math.log(window / h) / Math.log(bounce)) - 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Even though it *comes* from code, this looks more like a mathematics question. Could you explain how it is actually a problem in practical computer programming, the topic of this site?

Comment: on codewars, they just give problems you need to code and solve, it was one i struggled with, just wanted to learn, so if i offended anyone

Comment: Your question is not bad, you just asked it on the wrong site. This particular site is about practical computer programming. A question like this is a better fit on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site. I see that you are already a member of multiple Stack Exchange sites--just join the mathematics one as well and ask there. The dividing line between math and computer programming questions is sometimes fuzzy, but as it stands now this is more a math question that is slightly related to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really is more a math problem, but...

With each bounce your ball bounces a fraction of the bounce before. So to make it easy imagine the bounce parameter is 0.5. Each bounce is half the height of the bounce before. If your window is at 1.0 the bounces will be:

```
1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16...
```

Another way to say this is the height of the bounce will be `bounce_rate ** n` where `n` is the number of bounces. The third bounce is `0.5 ** 3` or `1/8`.

Now if you are given a height and you asked which bounce that height corresponds to, you will need to solve the equation `height = bounce_rate ** n` for `n`. Solving for `n` requires a log — in this case `n = log(base bounce_rate)height.` log base `bounce_rate` is inconvenient, but you can rewrite this as `log(height)/log(bounce_rate)`. In concrete terms to figure which bounce gets to `1/16` the window height, you just calculate `log(1/16)/log(0.5)` and get `4`.

So you should be able to start see how this resembles your equation. But since our equation is using height as a fraction of window height, we need to turn that height into something relative to the mothers window. So instead of figuring out when the ball will bounce to something like 1/16 the height of the drop window we want to know when the ball reaches a different ratio — that of the drop window to the mother's — `window/h` — if the mother's window as at 5 and the ball is dropped from 20, that would be calculating `1/4` which as we previously showed would be `log(1/4)/log(bounce_rate)` or `log(window/h)/log(bounce)`

That's the meat of it. The rest of the equation is dealing with the fact that window is not necessarily an exact solution to log equation, so we round with `Math.ceil` and the fact that the ball appears in front off the window once on the way down, but twice each time it bounces past window height.

Comment: man i am gonna mark as correct but, i still don't get it, I normally can figure out most thing i come across so this is really bugging me. So when you say
`log(base bounce_rate) height.`
you are saying `log of height base bounce_rate`?

Comment: @Lpc_dark I personally find logs confusing, I think most people do. But crux of the issue is that you are solving for a variable that's an exponent — solving for `n` in `x^n` to do that you need to take a log of `X`.

Comment: logs allow you to solve for an exponent given that you know the result and the number the exponent is being applied to? correct?

Comment: The reason why i am obsession over this is that everyone was having their code time out trying to do it recursively and was failing the test and one dude just got it in one line. and it was crazy numbers that forced the computer to do massive calculations but he was able to do it in one line.

Comment: @Lpc_dark correct. So solving `16 = 2 ^ n` you calculate `n = log2(16)` and get 4. `2^4 = 16`. It just gets a little more confusing in your example because the base isn't 2 — the base is the bounce rate.

Comment: its the division part that my mind starts to spin, i will spend a little bit more time on this when i get home and i can write it out and see it. Thank you soo much.

Comment: @Lpc_dark One more point — the division is needed because it's hard to take a log to an arbitrary base. But there's a log law that lets you do it. For example if you wanted to find `log2(16)` but only had a `log10` function you can use `log10(16)/log10(2)` to find log 16 base 2. The division allows you to calculate the log base bounce_rate. In javascript `Math.log10(16)/Math.log10(2)` is the same as `Math.log2(16)`